# How to raise onError from chunking success endpoint in Fine-uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

In my application, when the chunking-success-endpoint returns JSON like `{"error": "reason..."}` (for example the server failed to put the chunks back together), the `onError` event is not being called.

Just to clarify, the `onError` event *is* called if individual chunks fail.  It's the final success request that I'm having trouble with.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Should I be handling this some other way?

My configuration is below.  Thanks in advance!

```
    var uploader = $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template',
        debug: true,
        callbacks: {
            onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
                $('#doclib_tree').jstree(true).refresh()
                if (failed.length > 0) {
                    alert("Error: Some files were not uploaded");
                } else {
                    if (succeeded.length > 0 ) {
                        alert("Successfully uploaded " + succeeded.length + " file(s)");
                    }
                    this.reset();
                    toggle_upload();
                }
            },
            onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                alert("Error uploading " + name + ".  Reason: " + errorReason)
            },
            onSubmit: function(id, name) {
                var promise = new qq.Promise();
                var dest = document.getElementById('dest_label').innerHTML.replace(/ &gt; /g, "/")
                $.ajax({
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'async': false,
                    'url': "/documents/exists" ,
                    'data': {
                        'parents' : get_path(dest),
                        'name': name,
                    },
                    'success': function(data, textStatus, jqHXR) {
                        if ( check_session(data) ) {
                            promise.failure();
                        } else {
                            if (confirm("The file '" + dest + "/" + name + "' already exists.  Replace?"))
                                promise.success();
                            else
                                promise.failure();
                        }
                    },
                    'error': function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        promise.success();
                    }
                });
                return promise;
            },
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true,
            partSize: 20000000, // 20MB
            success: {
                endpoint: "documents/upload?success=1",
            }
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true,
            recordsExpireIn: 1, // 1 day
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: "/documents/upload",
        },
        autoUpload: true
    });
```

Comment: Is the file actually marked as failed in the UI, or is that not working as well?

Comment: Upload is considered successful by the UI.  However, if the chunking-success-endpoint returns a 502 or invalid JSON, then the onError event _does_ fire and the file is marked as failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation under the chunking success section:

> For successful responses, you may return an empty body with a status of 200-204. Any other status code is determined to be a failure.

In other words, to indicate failure, you must return a status code that *indicates* failure. Pick the most appropriate status code given the context of the error. At that point, Fine Uploader should determine that the file has failed in some way, and your `onError` handler will be called with the `error` property returned by your server.